# Is partial type inference possible?

Tags: c#

Given the following code:

```
    public static TUnbox UnboxAndNullCheck<TUnbox, TBox>(TBox obj, string msg = "Unboxing error") where TUnbox : class, TBox
    {
        var unboxObj = obj as TUnbox;
        if (unboxObj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException( msg );
        return unboxObj;
    }
```

It seems calling it requires both type parameters as so:

```
UnboxAndNullCheck<SubClass, BaseClass>( obj );
```

Is it possible to call it in a way where you do not have to specify the type of obj?

```
UnboxAndNullCheck<SubClass>( obj );
```

Comment: I dont think so its possible just like we cant have `Dictionary<int>`

Comment: What does this give your calling code that just using `as` does not?

Comment: Also, it uses ArgumentNullException incorrectly; ANE is for when an argument is null, not for when something in code is null (that's what NullReferenceException is for), resulting in a null. This would be confusing to fellow developers - "why am I getting Arg Null when I'm certainly providing something that has a value?"

Comment: I gave an example to illustrate the question I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the type?

```
public static TUnbox UnboxAndNullCheck<TUnbox> (object obj, string msg = "Unboxing error") where TUnbox : class
```

But I'm really not sure what this gives you over just using `is` and `as`.. other than confusingly throwing an error in runtime saying an argument passed didn't have a value when it clearly did, and I'm really not sure what it gives you over just doing a cast. If TBox can be cast to TUnbox, it works. If it doesn't, it throws an exception

```
//this
var x = UnboxAndNullCheck<TUnbox>(myTBox);

//is just the same as this, except this is more compact  and throws the right exception
var x = (TUnbox)myTBox;
```